# Getting Last Azure Blob in the container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, generic-list, azure-blob-storage

I have a list of blobs with the following names in my container

eg.
item1
item2
item3
item9
item10
item12
item45

I want to get the first and last blob, which in this case is item1 and item45

However when i use cloudblobclient.cloudblobdirectory.listblobs.last, item9 was returned to me, not what I wanted. What would be the best way to get the last item (45) from the list.

Can only think of running through the full list, then for each item, get the number after  the characters "item" and compare that number to previous high or low. Since the first 4 characters are fixed, I will combine the "item" and higherCnt:

```
for each blobitem in listblobs
  iCurrCnt = numeric(blobitem.uri.absolutepath.substring(4)) 
  if iCurrCnt > iHigherCnt then
  iHigherCnt = iCurrCnt
```

thus the blob that was the last (item45):

```
strHighestCntFileName = "item" + iHigherCnt
```

Is there an alternate way to do this? Worries about performance when the item list grows to thousands. I am only interested in the first and last blob. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the criteria for deciding for 1st and last blob? Is it by name like you have in example above or can it change? Can it be assumed that 1st blob would be the one which is added first and the last blob would be the one which is added last?

Comment: Can you change the way the blobs are named? Zero-Padding with integer.ToString("D8") Will give you item00000001 item0000002 etc which you can then just sort on alphabetically for the right result  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Comment: Yes, the criteria to decide 1st and last blob is like the example shown based on the numerical values after the word "item". Not necessary, the last blob (45 in example) can be added first and first blob (1 in example) can be added last.

Comment: Zero-Padding sounds like a good idea, probably can consider that option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are following ways you can achieve this thing:

- Get the list of all blob existing in container and then filer blob which you want.
- Use blob prefix when listing blobs existing in container. So if you have an idea of 1st and last blob name then you can use it in blob prefix, which will return you the list of blobs matching specified blob prefix.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Amit jain
www.cerebrata.com